# Where I can translate "ForgotPassword" page in Identity in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have to translate "ForgotPassword" page and "ResendEmailConfirmation" page.
In Login.cshtml I have

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <p>
        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Nie pamiętasz hasła?</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Utwórz konto</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Wyślij ponownie potwierdzenie e-mailem</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

But this pages don't exist in Solution Explorer, I also tried to find text "Forgot your password?" and "resend" via Notepad++ function "find in folder" in project folder, but no result.

Answer (score 3):

You must scaffold the Identity pages into your project.

This will create all of the pages in your project so you can modify them.

The instructions are here: [Scaffold Identity into an existing project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-without-existing-authorization)

1. From Solution Explorer (in VS), right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
2. From the left pane of the Add New Scaffolded Item dialog, select Identity > Add.
3. In the Add Identity dialog, select the options you want. Select all pages so you can translate them all.